# Trying to extract text through OCR space API in react native but receiving an error as incorrect base64 format

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, base64, http-post, ocr

```
After clicking an image through android mobile and extracting base64 from the image,  I am sending it to the OCR space API to extract the text in the image.
```

getTextByURL is subjected to call the API after receiving the base64.

The format should be data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS....

To obtain the format I am appending the base64 code to 'data:image/png;base64,' which should satisfy the required POST call conditions.

But the error still persists, I could not find whether the error is in the format or in the base64 code.

When I give a base64 code of an image in the POST call instead of base64 generated from the clicked image, the API call is working.

So no idea where is the glitch.
please help me!

```
getTextByUrl(base) {
    var url = "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image";
    var subscriptionKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("apikey", subscriptionKey);
    data.append("language", "eng");
    data.append("isOverlayRequired", "true");
    data.append("Base64Image", base)
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        alert(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "URL");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.send(data);

  }

  showCamera() {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
      uri: ""
    })
  }
```

The following function is to click the image and extract the base64 from the image.

```
  takePicture() {
    const options = {};
    //options.location = ...
    this.camera.capture({ metadata: options })
      .then((data) => {
        let pathToImage = data.path;

        CompressImage.createCompressedImage(pathToImage, 'compress/images').then(

          ImgToBase64.getBase64String(pathToImage)
            .then(base64String => {
              **base64String = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;**//This gives the base64 of the image

              alert(base64String.substring(0, 50) + typeof (base64String));


              this.setState({
                baa: base64String.substring(0, 200)
              })
              this.getTextByUrl(base64String)
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err))
        )


      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be replace "**Base64Image**" with "**base64Image**". This works for me

```
const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
  const base64Str = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+data.base64; var data = new FormData();  
data.append('apikey', key)
data.append('base64Image', base64)

const headers = { 
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
 }
const config = { 
  method: 'POST', 
  headers,
  body: data
 };
const URL = 'https://api.ocr.space/parse/image';

fetch(URL, config )
```

Comment: If this is the answer, it's a typo and the question should be closed as such.

Comment: I have tried the above solution but did resolve my problem. But thanks for trying.